# Keeping translate css (x,y) values same for all screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, translate-animation

I have been using translate css (translate(100,200)) for my object animation. But there's a problem with it i have a different resolution and when im putting some different co-ordinates for another screen so my object goes out of my screen. Please help that how can i use translate css for all screens?

Comment: how about using percentage? like `translate(20%, 40%)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pixel measurements it's impossible to have something work on all resolutions unless you are always assuming the smallest, which is unviable for larger screens.

So you have two basic solutions:

- Use percentage based positioning, the main issue with this is that you never have true control over where your elements will be positioned on screen, since 20% of a 320px wide screen is vastly different from 20% on a 1920px wide display.
- Use media queries, this is probably the best solution, it does involve a bit more work though. I reccommend setting your canvas/container to a specific width/height on each resolution jump, this way you can probably get away with 3 or 4 different sizes.

An important thing to note is that you can combine both at some points depending on your exact needs, here's a basic example for how i'd set the container's sizes up:

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;
}
.container .child {
    /*animation stuff*/
}
@media (max-width: 1199px){
    .container {
        width: 900px;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .container .child {
        /* animation adjustments */
    }

}
/* etc... */
```

Another neat thing about setting up static sizes is that you have better control with your percentages, specially if you keep the width/height proportions equal.

Comment: Note that  translate in percentage refers to the size of the element, not to the size of the screen.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm sayng in my last paragraph. the point is that if the container's size is a percentage of available space, you lose a lot of control.

Comment: Well thanks for that @BrianH. But i have kind of figured out a way tell me is it the best one? As for a 1920x1080 screen i have asked the guy to give me the co-ordinates divided by the resolution like 700/1920 and vice versa. So i can multiply the answer with my resolution's width. It kind of solves for that but i have to put cases then for alot of other screens i dont wanna get caught up with media queries?